# How to do motion track with the camera movement

Tags: motion-capture

The camera still keep rotating ,moving  and I want to put the 3D model in the scene.If all track points keep in the camera view its ok to track but confused me is the track points only can keep a while then disabled with the camera movement.

So the setting floor actually only keep a while not always there.
If the 3D models keep movement with the camera its hard to keep it.

I dont know how to do this kind of track.
For example ,the camear move from bottom to top of the building ,the 3D model need up with the camera
[sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11mU3jHReNeyQ4OG7QD38VLfYjOynEDyL)

[sample clip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tmkvk4aqxYR7ov47Tm4ECzwfUkBOz_7_)